# When used project template for Visual Studio 2013 this debugging another project

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I used a project template to build my projects, but when I run my design it shows another project being debugged.

My template was extracted from : AM.SLN

My new project call : SB.sln

[image]

When I debug my new project, the localhost has proved so:

[image]

So, How I can fix this problem ?

Ps. Sorry for my English I'm Brazilian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because when I exported my template the port of localhost is exported too
[image]